# Absolute position for android

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a screen that looks like the attached picture. The styling code I used works only for **iOS** but doesn't work for **Android**.

The sample code with preview can be found here: https://snack.expo.io/@tushark/absolute-android

Please check for both iOS and android.

**Here is the layout I want to create.**

[image]

Comment: [this is what you want?](https://snack.expo.io/S1yDf4Q47)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've create a new `Expo` project from a sample code you give here: https://snack.expo.io/S1yDf4Q47

On the `AbsoluteView` Component add another `View` to handle the display screen:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={{borderColor:'transparent'}}> // add borderColor, or the screen looks weird on android (i don't know why)
    {View of card, row, title and content styles}
  </View>
  <OrangeButton
      label="CONFIRM"
      onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}
      styleButton={styles.loginBtn}
  />
</View>
```

and the `Button` Component I change the `Bottom: -20` to `top: width / 3,`

and the layout look's like :

**Android :**

[image: Android]

**iOS:**

[image: iOS]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend leaving the orange button outside of the card container and using an absolute position with device height to position it, you can also do the same for the card container to give the button the same position relevant to the card container on any device.

ex. 
top: Dimensions.get('window').height/8

Comment: Hmm. Can you try to demonstrate in the snack I provided? The `absolute` position doesn't seem to affect on android.

Comment: removed it from card view, it wasnt working because it was basing itself on card view

Comment: I can't remove the card view. I was provided with this design and had to do exactly like it.

Comment: you dont have to remove it you just have to place the button outside of the card view